# get location of video, on page – JS

Tags: javascript

I have a `video`, here with: `class="myVideo"` and this video has `autoplay`, but it might take the browser a couple of seconds to load the video so that it can be played and so I want to add a loading screen.

I wrote a script that, on page load, runs every 10 milliseconds and checks if my `video` is already loaded and when it is, it stops running and it tells me that the `video` is loaded so that I can then remove the loading screen, that I want to first place over my video.

> **My Problem:**
>
> How can I detect the exact size and position of `.myVideo` on the page and translate that to `.myLoadingScreen`? (When the page is loaded.)

> **This is what I have so far:**
>
> `document.querySelector(".myLoadingScreen").style.top = document.querySelector(".myVideo").getBoundingClientRect().top + "px";`

This seems right, but I tried a bunch of things and I did a lot of testing and I just can't get it to work. – It works very occasionally, but most of the time `".myLoadingScreen"` is place somewhere at a pretty random location. – But occasionally it does work.

First I thought it's because the browser may need a little bit of time to draw the `video` and my script just takes the location of the `video` too early and so I added a `setTimeout`, but even a long timeout does not change anything.

I really tried to figure this out, but I have no idea what's going on…

Comment: You shouldn't have to do this. Place the video and div into the same container, with the loading div layered over the video. When you do not need the loader anymore, simply give it `display: none;`

Comment: @Laif I kind of, tried to avoid this, because this means I have to rewrite a bunch of stuff, but you're right. I should do this. –  Maybe someone sends me a working solution soon, but if not, I will do what you suggested. Thank You!

Comment: Shouldn't have to do anything but add a single div

Comment: All this trouble with 10ms queries etc. All you have to do for that part is listen for the `<video>` element's [canplay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplay_event) event. As for the position of the video element itself, that is captured in the [.getBoundingClientRectangle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Comment: @Laif I had to change a couple of media queries, but yeah, it wasn't that much work, should have done this from the start, now I know. ;)

Comment: @RandyCasburn I know about `getBoundingClientRect()`, I actually used it in my question. ;) It just didn't work. – I did not know about `canplay` and I will look into this now, Thank You!

Comment: It didn't work because you didn't use it properly - please review the documentation I linked.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Ah, now I see… I did not know that `getBoundingClientRect()` takes scrolling into account.